# Why was this spam flag on an answer disputed​?

Tags: discussion, spam, disputed-flags

Yesterday I flagged [this (now deleted) **answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852758/bootstrap-4-navbar-collapse-hide-open-others/48853352#48853352) (the question is **not** at fault), as spam. When I checked later, I found that the flag was marked as `disputed`, but the post was deleted anyway.

I just wonder what it was, if not spam? The **answer** was written in Dutch and offered (IIRC) some kind of financial service and a contact email address, totally unrelated to the question and the **answer** was clearly spam.

Comment: It certainly looks like spam to me. As you said, the Google translate translation indicates that they are offering loans ("Need money urgently? We will help you further!") and asking you to contact them via the provided email address ("State the amount you want to borrow and we will contact you to go through all the options."). I definitely would have confidently flagged it as spam.

Comment: Could the problem be that the question is in dutch and whoever handled the flag wasn't able to understand the content? I'm German speaking, so I understand enough to judge it as spam, but I guess for an English native it might be hard to judge between spam and just an answer in another language. The answer was also not deleted as spam, there would be a warning there instead of the text (for >10k).

Comment: It is SPAM for sure. Might be that the moderator opted for a VLQ flag, which is used for non-English content as they probably couldn't judge the content being spam or not.

Comment: thanks for confirming me. @BDL I just used google translate, as Mayken did. And that's what the mod should have done too, I often find posts written in many different languages here and use google translate to judge if it's spam, abusive or a user just forgetting to post in english.

Comment: You can always ask in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to either help in judging a post for being spam  or expedite removal of such spam posts.

Comment: thanks @rene, will check that chat if I'm in doubt.

Comment: @jps You can also let us know in chat if you're sure it's spam. We have ways of promoting the spam post which tends to remove the need for mods entirely (spam/rude can be automatically sustained with enough regular users flagging). In fact, I'm surprised this was missed by some other anti-spam efforts

Comment: Because all caps.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: of course all caps: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Spam_can.png/220px-Spam_can.png what else?

Comment: @jps ^^^^touché

Comment: Could someone add a screenshot so that users with less than 10k reputation can understand what the question is about?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Makyen already posted the translation of it in the first comment above. Nothing special about it besides the fact it was written in dutch,

Comment: Just checked and it's visible/undeleted again?!? Am I missing something? I've flagged it again.

Comment: @cfi You see the answer, that was deleted as spam, or the question?

Comment: @Adinia, my bad: The answer is deleted and I cannot see it (correct behaviour). I was confused because I thought the Q itself should be considered spam, because the image itself points to a commercially viable url in big letters. My flag was rejected and SOCVR agrees with that, also taking the rep of the user into account. While I disagree I also believe the Q is not the big deal, and I cannot judge the answer

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That's because I didn't translate the post.

It needed deleting, but as I couldn't immediately see a link I decided that it wasn't actually spam.

My bad. I should have translated it first - something that I normally do do.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As I said above in the comments, I think it's always important to translate first.

Comment: @jps - yeah. And I normally do. Just a brain fart moment.

Comment: ok, no problem, we all make mistakes. Just wanted to know if my judgement was correct.

Comment: "I normally do do".. do do.. do-do.. [dodo](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/external/slideshow/full/Dodo_full.jpg)

Comment: Even without translating, the e-mail address is quite recognizable.

Comment: @BenVoigt There's two reasons users posts emails. The first is spam (as is the case here). The second is they're looking for specific help and want someone to email them. Both are subject to deletion, but spam/rude should be reserved for those that need the extra penalty. Hence why translation is necessary here